Почему при передаче "\n" в JSON.stringify() вертикальный отступ увеличивается с каждым уровнем вложенности?
Я хотел немного изменить отображение выводимой JSON строки, но столкнулся с тем, что при наличии вложенных обьектов, вертикальный отступ по какой-то причине увеличивается с каждым уровнем вложенности. Чем может быть вызвано такое поведение и как его пофиксить?


let user = {
  prop1: 1,
  prop2: { 
      prop1: 2,
      prop2: {
          prop1: 3
      }
  }
};
console.log(JSON.stringify(user, null, "\n  "));




Потому что если там передать не пустую строку, то функция сама добавляет к нему ещё и \n от себя. Давая \n вы получаете \n\n.

Уберите перевод строки из третьего параметра. Ещё лучше прямо в вопросе напишите что вы хотите.

Третий параметр метода JSON.stringify отвечает за отступ слева (indentation) для каждого уровня вложенности (т.е. если Вы укажете пробел то следующий уровень вложености после него будет отображен как 2 пробела, потом 3 и т.д.)
В вашем конкретном случае получается отступ по вертикали и только он (потому что \n переводит каретку и препятсвует росту отступа вправо) Я отобразил то что происходит на иллюстрации ниже, надеюсь будет понятнее.
Решение: Пофиксить можно только убрав перевод каретки (он итак вставляется при наличии третьего аргумента в вызове метода)

